# Visit counter with mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, counter

At first I'm beginner at php and MySQL. Now I'm working on my first bigger website with Administration panel. I want to do a simple visit counter with mysql and php. I made this code, where visitors IP save in $ip and Insert in DB. Looks easy, but it doesn't work :D I spend about 2 hours on it, but I can't find a mistake in my code. It doesn't show me any information in DB.

```
include 'connect_db.php';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE visits='$ip'");
if (!$ip == $sql) {
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (visits) VALUES '$ip'");
}
```

I have 2 items in my table. 1) ID with Auto Increment and 2) visits defined as VARCHAR 50. 
Server connection is ok, doesn't show any error.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Save your time learning `mysql_*` API - It's deprecated. Switch to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: `!$ip == $sql` looks very weird. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plz try this.
i hope it could be help

```
include 'connect_db.php';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
if (isset($ip)){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE visits = '$ip'");
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==0){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (visits) VALUES ('$ip')");
 }
}
```

Comment: Oh .. IT WORKS!! Thank you so much (>^^)>

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, I found the mistake .. one of them was statement (Thank you ImAtWar) and other mistake was after "VALUES" in INSERT must be in () ...

But it didn´t work properly. It insert IP in db again even when is inserted once. :l

Repaired code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitcont WHERE visits='$ip'");
if ($ip !== $sql) {
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO visitcount (visits) VALUES ('$ip')");
```

Comment: visitcount table only have 2 colums  Id and visits??

Comment: Yes, just 2 colums

Answer (score -1):

You have to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. But for now try this:

```
include 'connect_db.php';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE visits= $ip");
if (!empty($ip) && ($ip != $sql)) {
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (visits) VALUES $ip");
}else{
   echo "already inserted";
}
```

Comment: This is still wrong. `mysql_query()` returns a resource. You cant compare it to a string like `$ip != $sql`.

Comment: Nothing happend :/